# 'The term 'New-ComplianceTag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

what should be done , how to remove this System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException error
when i try to invoke this command in powershell using c#
but i works fine when i do it directly in powershell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yuLY.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your code? What are your imports? Please read on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is an Exchange Online cmdlet for the Security & compliance Center. The Exchange Online module loads cmdlets remotely from Microsoft. It will only load the cmdlets you have permissions for.

My best guess is that you're missing the permissions for this cmdlet/ setting.

Comment: it works using cmdlets in powershell
but when i try to invoke it using C# it gives this error

Comment: You invoke the command, but do you also connect to exchange remotely?